# I want to create a table where the header text is vertically aligned. I've tried different methods but none seem to work. Help me to design this

Tags: php, pdf, html-table, tcpdf

```php
if (isset($_POST['convert_to_pdf'])) {

  require_once('../TCPDF-main/main/tcpdf.php');

  $pdf = new TCPDF('landscape', PDF_UNIT, 'LEGAL', true, 'UTF-8', false);

  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetTitle('HTML to PDF');

  $pdf->SetHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->SetFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
  $pdf->SetMargins(1, 10, 1); // Adjust margins as needed
  $pdf->setCellPaddings(1, 5, 1, 5); // Adjust cell paddings as needed

  // Disable header and footer
  $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
  $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);

  // Enable automatic page breaking
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);

  // Set default font
  $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

  // Add a new page to the PDF
  $pdf->AddPage();

  // HTML content for the table
  $html =
  '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #fefefe;">
              <th width="55" height="61">Enrollment No.</th>
              <th width="55" height="70" ">Candidate\'s Name</th>
              <th width="55" height="30" style="text-align: center;">Sex</th>
              <th width="55" height="40" style="text-align: center;">Caste</th>
              <th width="55" height="45" style="text-align: center;">Religion</th>
              <th width="55" height="46" style="text-align: center;">Subject</th>
              <th width="55" height="42" style="text-align: center;">Th.Marks</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
  </table>';

  // Write HTML content to the PDF
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

  // Generate unique filename for the PDF
  $fileName = "sample_" . time() . ".pdf";

  // Output the PDF as a download
  $pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
  exit;
}
```

The provided PHP code generates a table using TCPDF library, but the table headers () appear horizontally aligned. The objective is to align these headers text vertically, as depicted in a provided sample image. Despite attempts to utilize CSS rotation properties within TCPDF, the desired vertical alignment remains elusive. I donot have nay idea.

Comment: Where is the `provided sample page` ?